# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qdarkstyle.colorsystem' in Ubuntu Spyder 5.3.0

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I have recently installed Ubuntu to try out its usage and efficiency with Spyder. Currently, after using pip to install the latest version of Spyder`(5.3.0)`, I got this error while trying to open it in my terminal.

```
from qdarkstyle.colorsystem import Blue, Gray
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qdarkstyle.colorsystem'
```

Any idea to solving this problem? I have seen posts for solving this using `conda` but it's for Windows, and they offer answers to install older version.

Comment: `pip install QDarkStyle` would be a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need to do is : `pip install qdarkstyle` then it will work [image]